# How can vue-cli support optional SCSS, such as for themes?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I know you can import scss/css in a component, but how would you handle optional scss? They would need to be built standalone and imported.

Say I have a light.scss and a dark.scss. I want to be able to build them along with everything else and be output to an css folder.

As far as switching themes, I'm pretty sure I can get away with just replacing a `link` element in the head of the page with the theme css file. I just need to be able to build the css files in the first place.

I've attempted to make multiple entries for the files, and this appears to work, but each entry has a bogus JS file generated as well. I could probably just ignore the JS file, but it seems like there must be a better way.

Comment: Not sure if this can be an answer, but you can try importing both scss files, and use a top level element (on say, body) to apply a class to and have your themes depend on that.